# How to modify the source code of a Go package

Tags: go, version-control, package

I'm trying to change the source code of the Sync package found in Go's *src* folder. More specifically, I need to alter the *waitgroup.go* file to export the *state()* function. Here is the source function:

```
func (wg *WaitGroup) state() (statep *uint64, semap *uint32) {
    if uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&wg.state1))%8 == 0 {
        return (*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&wg.state1)), &wg.state1[2]
    } else {
        return (*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&wg.state1[1])), &wg.state1[0]
    }
}
```

All I need to do is captialize the name of this function so that I can use it in my code (I simply need to check if the waitgoup counter is greater than 0). I'm using Go Modules and the only solution I have found so far is to manually change the *waitgroup.go* file in the *src* folder. This is not ideal because the changes are not checked into version control. I've also tried recreating the *waitgroup.go* file within my codebase, but this leads to errors because the file imports packages found in Go's *internal* folder.

How can I change the code of this Go *src* package all the while keeping track of the changes with version control (github)?

**EDIT**

For some context, I'm designing a peer to peer network for cryptocurrency. The below code is part of my peer discovery system. Essentially, when joining the network for the first time, a node will make a request to a DNS server over tcp and randomly select a node. It then makes a request to the node (genesis node), asking for its local set of nodes. Once this request is done, that is when the genesis node has responded, the program moves to the second discovery cycle. I'm using a waitgroup wait for the first cycle to finish.

Here is the function that will add a waitgroup:

```
func HandleGenesisNode(request []byte) {
var buff bytes.Buffer
var payload RecieveGenesisNode

buff.Write(request[commandLength:])
dec := gob.NewDecoder(&buff)
err := dec.Decode(&payload)
Handle(err)

//Initialize set with newly discovered node
InitSet(payload.GenesisNode)
//peer discovery first cycle
discoveryCycleOneWg.Add(1)
GetNodeSet(payload.GenesisNode)
//peer discovery second cycle once first has finished
discoveryCycleOneWg.Wait()

//Request the set of every node in the newly generated set
localSet := LocalSetToBytes()
for i := range localSet {
    node := string(localSet[i])
    GetNodeSet(node)
}
```

}

Here is the function that removes a waitgroup to indicate that first cycle is done:

```
func HandleLocalSet(request []byte) {
var buff bytes.Buffer
var payload LocalSet

buff.Write(request[commandLength:])
dec := gob.NewDecoder(&buff)
err := dec.Decode(&payload)
Handle(err)

fmt.Println("Comparing sets...")
state, newNodes := CompareSet(payload.Set)
if state == true {
    UpdateSet(newNodes)
} else {
    fmt.Println("No new nodes discovered")
}

//allow second cycle to start if this is a response to discovery
//Check the waitgroup counter before decrementing it
_, wgState := discoveryCycleOneWg.State()
counter := uint32(wgState)
if counter > 0 {
    discoveryCycleOneWg.Done()
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to track the state of a WaitGroup? There's plenty of synchronization mechanisms available in Go to track the progress of your workers without having to replicate the internals of the standard library.

Comment: You modify the source exactly like you mentioned. (and what you are doing is not safe, since wait groups are designed to be concurrently accessed; not to mention your code would not portable to any where else without the forked go std library)

Comment: @colm.anseo Thanks for the reply. I'm designing a P2P network and I have a function which calls waitgroup.Done() on a shared waitgroup. This same function is called for several purposes that do not necessarily call waitgroup.Add(), which results in a negative waitgroup counter. Unfortunately I cannot break that function up into multiple functions.

Comment: WaitGroup is a counter - and yes it should never go negative - but it's typical use is for goroutine completeness tracking. It may not be the best fit for you here. Update your question with the code pieces you are trying to coordinate & maybe we can help.

Comment: colm.anseo Good idea, I've added a couple function which should illustrate the issue in question. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"

    _ "unsafe"
)

//go:linkname state sync.(*WaitGroup).state
func state(wg *sync.WaitGroup) (*uint64, *uint32)

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    statep, _ := state(&wg)
    stateWg := atomic.LoadUint64(statep)
    v := int32(stateWg >> 32)
    fmt.Printf("%d", v)
}
```

Documentation about [linkname](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!